# how python system call returns?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a probably naive question regarding python system call behavior. I am wondering if `os.system()` will return right away after the cmd is called or it will wait any the cmd finish to return.

Similarly question for subprocess module. I think subprocess will return right way after it was called as it spawns a child process. But I am not sure about `os.system()`. There is no doc regarding this.

Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way is to check it yourself by calling `sleep 60` or similar, long-running job.

Comment: Returns the exit status of the call, IIRC

Comment: if you assign `t = os.system(your_call)` , then call `t` and  `print t` after you will see the exit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) documentation says the following:

> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in
>   the format specified for wait(). Note that POSIX does not specify the
>   meaning of the return value of the C system() function, so the return
>   value of the Python function is system-dependent.
>
> On Windows, the return value is that returned by the system shell
>   after running command, given by the Windows environment variable
>   COMSPEC: on command.com systems (Windows 95, 98 and ME) this is always
>   0; on cmd.exe systems (Windows NT, 2000 and XP) this is the exit
>   status of the command run; on systems using a non-native shell,
>   consult your shell documentation.

For `os.system` to return these values, it must wait for the program to complete and provide an exit code. Also, it says

> This is implemented by calling the Standard C function system(), and
>   has the same limitations.

The documentation for the [C `system` function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) says

> system() executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c
>   command, and returns after the command has been completed.

So it has to wait for the command to complete.

---

As for `subprocess`, the `call`, `check_call`, and `check_output` convenience function all wait for the command to complete. `call` and `check_call` say this explicitly, while `check_output` returns the command's output as a byte string, which requires it to wait for the command to finish.

`subprocess.Popen` does not wait for the command to complete. It has several methods to check whether the command has completed or wait for the command to complete, such as `Popen.wait`.

Answer (score 1):

> The `system()` function shall not return until the child process has terminated.

From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html which the Python library refers to when it states:

> This is implemented by calling the Standard C function `system()`, and has the same limitations.

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system